# book on numerical riemannian geometry

Tags: numerical-methods, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

I tried to get a basic understanding of Riemannian geometry at least half a dozen of times, each time failing miserably because the concepts slip quicker from my mind than i can read up on them. My background is computer-science, especially optimization, machine-learning and statistics and I have taken a few proper math classes (One year of studying math). While i don't have trouble with mathematics per-se, I have problems remembering and relating abstract concepts without proper intuition and practice. As a computer-scientist this often means, that the best way for me to remember a concept, is to implement and visualize it. But this is quite challenging with Riemannian geometry on its own (especially as notation often varies significantly from a computer implementation and numerics are often non-trivial) - and in the books i have found, actually computing things was never a priority.

Does someone have a recommendation of a numerics focused book on Riemannian Geometry that I can read in parallel to the theory books I have and use it to implement some of the things?

Comment: My guess is that you aren't really understanding what you're reading. Can you give a couple of examples of something you didn't understand? What text are you using? What prerequisites do you already have?

Comment: There is [discrete differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_differential_geometry) (see the cited literature and other works by these people). By avoiding limits this can be on the one hand more intuitive and geared towards numerical problems, on the other hands avoiding limits also avoids the corresponding simplifications and idealizations of only considering first-order effects.

Comment: @MPW  already said that i don't understand many things, because I fail making a connection between them. There are just so many different notations and concepts thrown around. I tried reading the book by Lee, recently read this: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02341901/file/chapter1.pdf there were probably a few other texts. With the Lee book specifically i had the problem that i could solve the assignments in each chapter individually but had no idea what any of that meant globally and two weeks later everything was gone.

As I said: 1 year math (LinAlg 1-2, Calculus 1-2 + phd in ML)

Comment: the thing where it typically falls apart is parallel transport, Levi-Civita connections and Christoffel-Symbols. When it comes to that i usually spent all my time looking up notation and definitions. I couldn't do any computations myself or tell you what most of that means. but e.g. arc-length are fine.

Comment: @Ulfgard: When I started reading Riemannian geometry, I was completely stupid. So it is natural for a Euclidean-Mind people and it is a little confusing. if you read something try to give or find (in internet or books) a concrete example for it. that may help.

Comment: You might have a look at [_Solid Shape_](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/solid-shape) by Jan Koenderink, who writes for engineers in a highly geometric way.